Altera Max10 DDR2 termination scheme
I am trying to interface a Altera Max 10 FPGA to Micron MT47H256M8 DDR2 chip. I am little big confused about the termination scheme.

Are the ODT75 terminations selectable in the memory chip by the FPGA?
Do you need on board 50ohm series resistors for DQ/DQS, DM and clock lines?
Do address and command lines require series resistors? seems to me it only require parallel resistors near the memory chip.



There should be some old reference designs available, where you can look for implementations, no?
